# How can I send a signal to a popen'ed process in Perl?

Tags: c, perl, signals

I wrote a simple Perl script which will run in while loop and exit whenever any signal is send to this Perl script. I wrote a c program which creates a thread using the `pthread_create()` and in its start routine, it's using `popen` to execute that Perl script:

```
popen("/usr/bin/perl myprog.pl");
```

I am using the `sigtrap` in the Perl script to catch any signal it receives. Now I want to send signal (TERM) from my C program to this Perl process executed by the thread. How can I do that? Is there any way to send a signal to `popen`'ed processes. Please let me know if need more details.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Sending signals usually works using `kill`. In order to be able to kill you normally need the process id, PID, of the process you want to signal.

`popen` doesn't give you that. However, there's a couple of alternatives:

You could use a PID of `0`, which would send your signal to every process in the process group. If you only have one parent process spawning one child process using `popen`, then using `kill(0, your_signal)` would be one way to go.

Another way to go would be to have the child process communicate its PID back to the parent process by, for example, just outputing that on a single line as the first thing after starting up.

In perl, that'd look like

```
print $$, "\n";
```

the process that did `popen` could then read that line from the filehandle it got, and extract a useful pid from that using `strtol` or `atoi`, and keep that around to use with `kill` later on, after having read the actual output of its child process.

If, for whatever reason, none of these approaches is viable for your problem, you probably want to stop using `popen` alltogether, and do most of what it does manually, most importantly the `fork`ing, as that's what'll give you the PID to use to later send signals.

Answer (score 2):

`popen()` doesn't give you any way to access the PID of the child process, which you need in order to signal it.

You will need to do the gory work of `popen()` yourself (set up pipes, fork, exec, wait).